# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes but audio keeps playing

Tags: 18.04, sound, freeze, crash

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on dual boot.

Sometimes (and I think I have isolated it to when media is playing, be it videos or songs), my Ubuntu suddenly freezes. Sometimes I can move the mouse around but everything is unresponsive, and sometimes the mouse freezes too. The audio keeps playing until e.g. the song ends or the YouTube video stops rendering.

I have tried doing Ctrl+Alt+F3, but it doesn't work. Sometimes it unfreezes after a long period of time.

Why would my Ubuntu crash when sound is being played?, how could I verify that the video and audio drivers are properly installed?

Thanks!

EDIT: More information about my graphics card.

The result of `sudo lspci | grep VGA`

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c4)
03:00.7 Non-VGA unclassified device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e6
```

Comment: is your sound also coming from YouTube?  are you viewing anything in fullscreen mode?

Comment: Sometimes is from sound from YouTube, but it has also happened with Spotify. I'm not running stuff in fullscreen usually.

Comment: Graphics card? And driver version,  if installed by you?

Comment: Hi, @GabrielaGarcia. I added the result of `sudo lspci | grep VGA`